# onclick event of input button type is not working in chrome for some users

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Here is my html code

```
<input type="button" name="Button" value="      Next      " runat="server" id="btnNext" class="button" onclick ="if (!EmptyCheck()) return false;"  />
```

and

```
function EmptyCheck() {
    debugger;
    var txtRSI = $("input[id$=txtRSI]").val();
    var txtQFix = $("input[id$=txtQFix]").val();
    var txtPassPercent = $("input[id$=txtPassPercent]").val();
    var txtDefRejRate = $("input[id$=txtDefRejRate]").val();
    var txtBuildVar = $("input[id$=txtBuildVar]").val();
    var txtEffortVar = $("input[id$=txtEffortVar]").val();
    var txtScheVar = $("input[id$=txtScheVar]").val();
    var txtDeliMet = $("input[id$=txtDeliMet]").val();
    var txtBudgetVar = $("input[id$=txtBudgetVar]").val();
    var ddlOwner = $('select[id$="ddlOwner"]').val();
    var ddlAccount = $('select[id$="ddlAccount"]').val();
    var ddlProgramme = $('select[id$="ddlProgramme"]').val();
    var ddlMonth = $('select[id$="ddlMonth"]').val();
    var ddlYear = $('select[id$="ddlYear"]').val();
    if ((txtRSI == "") || (txtQFix == "") || (txtPassPercent == "") || (txtDefRejRate == "") || (txtBuildVar == "") || (txtEffortVar == "") || (txtScheVar == "") ||
    (txtDeliMet == "") || (txtBudgetVar == "") || (ddlOwner == "-1") || (ddlAccount == null) || (ddlProgramme == null) || (ddlMonth == 0) || (ddlAccount == "-1")
    || (ddlProgramme == "-1") || (ddlYear == 0)) {
        alert("All fields are Mandatory");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is javascript method works fine in my browser.whereas the same is not working for others.

couldnt find why this happens..

inline code is not supported in chrome..i saw this in several posts..but it works for me..but not for others.. can somebody give an alternate solution to this???

also i have server side implememnted...wanted to achieve both.

i have tried like this also

```
getelementbyid('btnid').addeventlistener('click', function()){}
```

Comment: use parseInt() and typeOf operator before you validate some of your values ex(0, -1, null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just using the function? If your function returns a boolean value, why are you checking it to then return *another* boolean value? Just return `EmptyCheck()`

However, I will say that using the inline functions in my experience has been a poor decision. The functions can be managed/called more efficiently from an external jscript file. Here's an example:

### Step 1

In your *.js* file, create a generic (but not anonymous) function for each page. For examples, we'll work in a hypothetical "Home" page.

```
function HomePageEvents() {
}
```

### Step 2

Now we have a function that will serve as a container for your home page's javascript . . . But of course we need to run the function at some point. Well, we want to make sure the function is run once the document is finished loading of course, since we'll likely need to reference elements of the rendered page. So let's go ahead and create an anonymous function that will trigger this container function (aka, HomePageEvents() function). In your Home page, add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready({function(){
        HomePageEvents();
    });
</script>
```

### Step 3

What was it we were trying to do again? Oh, right! We want to add a click event for your button. Well, we can first start by creating the function for the click event. Now, I'm assuming your button has some kind of innate functionality, and all we are doing here is validating the button. If this is indeed the case, all we need to do is return a true or false indicating whether the event should continue.

```
function HomePageEvents() {
   // Function to perform our validation.
   function validateNext() {
      if ((txtRSI == "") || (txtQFix == "") || (txtPassPercent == "") || (txtDefRejRate == "") || (txtBuildVar == "") || (txtEffortVar == "") || (txtScheVar == "") || (txtDeliMet == "") || (txtBudgetVar == "") || (ddlOwner == "-1") || (ddlAccount == null) || (ddlProgramme == null) || (ddlMonth == 0) || (ddlAccount == "-1") || (ddlProgramme == "-1") || (ddlYear == 0)) {
        alert("All fields are Mandatory");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
   };
};
```

### Step 4

Now that we have the validation function ready, we just need to add the function as a click event for our btnNext button.

```
function HomePageEvents() {
   // Add function to btnNext button . . .
   $('#btnNext').on('click', function(){
      validateNext();
   });

   // Function to perform our validation.
   function validateNext() {
      if ((txtRSI == "") || (txtQFix == "") || (txtPassPercent == "") || (txtDefRejRate == "") || (txtBuildVar == "") || (txtEffortVar == "") || (txtScheVar == "") || (txtDeliMet == "") || (txtBudgetVar == "") || (ddlOwner == "-1") || (ddlAccount == null) || (ddlProgramme == null) || (ddlMonth == 0) || (ddlAccount == "-1") || (ddlProgramme == "-1") || (ddlYear == 0)) {
        alert("All fields are Mandatory");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
   };
};
```

The end result is you get (1) all your javascript in a single file--which is better for caching, (2) the file is easily manageable, and (3) you can isolate code for each page.

Comment: Sorry guys ..its works fine...proxy was not enabled in some machines..tat seems to be problem..but i really dont get this..wat does proxy has to do with this???

Comment: @user3514649 it was just some unsolicited advice from me to you. You asked for troubleshooting advice on your click-event assigned via an inline javascript function--which I answered--but I also wanted to explain why you might not want to set the click-event via an inline javascript function to begin with. Typically better to assign the click-events in the *.js* file (in my experience). But in the end, it's your code so do what makes you happy :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate you can use jQuery click event. Read documentation from [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/) .

```
$('.button').click(function(){ // button is the class name of your input control
 // Your EmptyCheck Logic goes here.
});
```

Note that there are other solutions as well to bind click event using jQuery like [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
// Your EmptyCheck Logic goes here.
});
```

Hope this helps!